# How to add a scala dependency to a Java project in intelliJ that use maven

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I want to use a scala dependency in a pure Java project. There is no need to write scala in my project but of course I will have to use classes/etc defined in the scala project that I add as a dependency. Want to do this in a intelliJ maven project.

My pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>group ID</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala dependancy</artifactId>
        </dependency>     
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Although I dont see any errors in pom, intellij is unable to import packages defined in the scala library. Essentially it cant find them.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you need (I don't use Scala), but it could look something like this:  `<groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.1</version>` (See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library)

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by adding the following  dependency to your pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
<!-- This plugin compiles Scala files -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
<!-- This plugin compiles Java files -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
<!-- This plugin adds all dependencies to JAR file during 'package' command.
Pay EXTRA attention to the 'mainClass' tag. 
You have to set name of class with entry point to program ('main' method) -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>ScalaRunner</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Take a look at [this](https://dzone.com/articles/scala-in-java-maven-project) for more information.

Comment: I dont know why I need such dependencies because there is no reason to compile scala code here. But I will test this out.

Comment: It didn't fix my issue unfortunately.